# How to make a buffer have specific latitude and longitude coordinates in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to create an annular buffer in GeoPandas (with an inner radius of 2 km and an outer radius of 2.1 km) around a specific point of latitude -33.0679433 and longitude -71.5524818

I did so by creating 2 buffers and turned them into GeoDataFrames so I could overlay them by difference like

`res_difference = buffer2_1gdf.overlay(buffer2gdf, how='difference')`

They are correctly overlayed, however, when I plot the map of the area I'm using it won't correctly plot. I viewed `res_difference` and it's geometry does not seem to be correct as its coordinates are not what I expect, it looks as if the coordinates are correlated with the values I gave the radiuses

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform the crs of your point's geometry to an appropriate one and get the buffer in meters. Example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

pt = Point( -33.0679433,  -71.5524818)
pt_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[pt], crs=4326)

buff1 = pt_df.copy()
buff1 = buff1.to_crs(3857)
buff1['geometry'] = buff1.geometry.buffer(2000)
buff1 = buff1.to_crs(4326)

buff2 = pt_df.copy()
buff2 = buff2.to_crs(3857)
buff2['geometry'] = buff2.geometry.buffer(2100)
buff2 = buff2.to_crs(4326)

res = gpd.overlay(buff2, buff1, how='difference')

ax = pt_df.plot()
res.plot(color='red', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```